# Word for defining the difference between "circumscribed" and "inscribed"

Tags: single-word-requests

So I am writing a program that works with regular polygons, and in part of that I need to represent circles that are inscribed and/or circumscribed upon the polygon.  As this is programming, I need to refer to the *relationship* between the polygon and these circles.  I have searched all around, but all of the places I have found that educate on calculating these circles never refer to this relational quality.

As I said, I need a way to refer to this relationship and I cannot seem to find a word that represents whether a circle has the quality of being circumscribed or inscribed upon a polygon.

Does any such word even exist?

This pseudocode example might help clarify what I am trying to find:

```
var myPolygon = new Hexagon();
var myCircle = CreateCircleOnPolygon(myPolygon, CircleType.Inscribed);
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
............
if (myCircle.CircleType == CircleType.Inscribed) { ... }
             ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The name emphasized in the above example is what I am currently using; however, considering that there are *lots* of different possible parts of my code that could need a different "type" of circle, the usage of the name `CircleType` is a little too broad in this context.

I suppose the word "quality" is what I am going for, but I thought I would reach out to the language experts to see if there is a term I am unaware of that is more appropriate.

Comment: The title seems to be asking a different question to the question body.

Comment: Mathematics.SE is more appropriate for such a subject-specific question, Robert. I'd bet there isn't a word for this.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say "relative position" in one word.

Comment: *position* or *size*? *Circle type* is also good - maybe you'll want to add a third type of circle to your software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "Bounded" and "Bounding" and label the `enum` CirclePlacement.

CirclePlacement.Bounded, CirclePlacement.Bounding.

Or ShapePlacement.Bounded, ShapePlacement.Bounding if you want to work with other shapes.

When the circle is **bounded** it is inside the polygon (contained within the polygon). When the circle is **bounding** it is outside the polygon (surrounding / containing the polygon).

The different participles (bounded, bounding) express the notion of relationship in natural English.

This is also extensible. There could be a CirclePlacement.Overlapped and CirclePlacement.Overlapping should you wish to make them color-filled and have one be partially "under" the other.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no better general term than that you chose, *type of circle*. This is the term used in an on line encyclopaedia ([Mathvox](https://mathvox.com/geometry/properties-of-circle/chapter-6-types-of-circles/)).

There is another possibility inspired by a fairly usual term as concerns the geometry of the triangle, I mean to refer to the term "*remarquable lines*"; you might use "*remarkable circles*". As has been mentioned in the comments, there is probably no umbrella term for just circumscribed and inscribed circles. There seems to exist no other term than "remarkable" for the lines of interest associated with triangles ([ref.](https://wikiejemplos.com/en/25-examples-of-remarkable-lines-and-points-of-a-triangle/)) ; so it is probably the case that there exists none for circles, and using the same term seems a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, there's probably not a word for this. You can just make up a composite term that expresses this choice:

```
myCircle.inOrCircumScribed = Geometry.Inscribed;
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any word for the relationship better than "relationship". And it's not a property of the circle, it's an attribute of the circle with respect to the polygon. So I would have `is_inscribed_in(circle, polygon)` or `circle.is_inscribed_in(polygon)`. I would also not have `CreateCircleOnPolygon`. It belongs in the Circle class namespace, not the main one, and you should have a general method, rather than one for this particular creation type. Some example code:

```
class Shape:
    circumscribing_shapes = []
    def is_inscribed_in(self, other):
        if other in self.circumscribing_shape:
            return True
        # [code to check whether self is inscribed in other]
        if is_inscribed:
            circumscribing_shapes.append(other)
            return True
        return False
    def __init__(self, how_and_args)):
        how, args = how_and_args
        self.__getattr__(how)(args)

class Circle(Shape):
    def inscribe(circumscribing_shape): 
        # [create a circle inscribed in containing shape]
        circumscribing_shapes.append(circumscribing_shapes)
    def center_and_radius(args):
        center, radius = args
        # [create a circle with given center and radius]
        
myCircle = Circle('inscribe', myPolygon)
unit_circle = Circle('center_and_radius', ((0,0),1))
```

Here, there's separate methods for initializing a circle depending on whether you're passing a circumscribed polygon or the circle's center and radius, but both are accessed externally through Circle's **init** method, with a parameter specifying which method to use.